# RedShift: some troubles with nested json

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have next JSON:

```
{"promptnum":4,"corpuscode":"B0014","prompttype":"video","skipped":false,"transcription":"1","deviceinfo":{"DEVICE_ID":"exynos980","DEVICE_MANUFACTURER":"samsung","DEVICE_SERIAL":"unknown","DEVICE_DESIGN":"a51x","DEVICE_MODEL":"SM-A5160","DEVICE_OS":"android","DEVICE_OS_VERSION":"10","DEVICE_CARRIER":"","DEVICE_BATTERY_LEVEL":"70.00%","DEVICE_BATTERY_STATE":"unplugged","Current App Version":"1.1.0","Current App Build":"6"}}
```

I want to get values from 1-st level and 2-nd level.

1-st level: `"promptnum":4,"corpuscode":"B0014","prompttype":"video","skipped":false,"transcription":"1","deviceinfo":...`

2-nd level:

```
"deviceinfo":{"DEVICE_ID":"exynos980","DEVICE_MANUFACTURER":"samsung","DEVICE_SERIAL":"unknown","DEVICE_DESIGN":"a51x","DEVICE_MODEL":"SM-A5160","DEVICE_OS":"android","DEVICE_OS_VERSION":"10","DEVICE_CARRIER":"","DEVICE_BATTERY_LEVEL":"70.00%","DEVICE_BATTERY_STATE":"unplugged","Current App Version":"1.1.0","Current App Build":"6"}
```

When I parse 1-st level with

```
SELECT d.*
FROM (
  SELECT c.json_parse, c.json_parse.deviceinfo AS device_info
  FROM (
      SELECT JSON_PARSE(file_attr)
      FROM public.dc_ac_files
  ) AS c) AS d
```

it's work well.

But when I try to get values from 2-nd level with

```
SELECT d.*, l.DEVICE_ID
FROM (
  SELECT c.json_parse, c.json_parse.deviceinfo AS device_info
  FROM (
      SELECT JSON_PARSE(file_attr)
      FROM public.dc_ac_files
  ) AS c) AS d, d.device_info AS l
```

it doesn't work - no errors and no data.

If I know, it's right way to parse nested json, but it doesn't work for me.

Can you help me?

Comment: Please use formatting. Putting long json strings on a single line is nonsense.  Would you put your code on a single line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viktor you have a couple of issues.  First the notation "AS d, d.device_info AS l" is used to unnest arrays in your super data.  You don't have any arrays to unnest so this is returning zero rows.

Second Redshift defaults to lower case for all column names so DEVICE_ID is being seen as device_id.  You can enable case sensitive column names by setting the enable_case_sensitive_identifier connection variable to true and quoting all column names that require upper characters.  "SET enable_case_sensitive_identifier TO true;" and changing l.DEVICE_ID to l."DEVICE_ID".

You also have unneeded layers in your query.

Putting all these together you can run:

```
SELECT l, l.deviceinfo, l.deviceinfo."DEVICE_ID" 
FROM (
    SELECT JSON_PARSE(file_attr) AS l
    FROM public.dc_ac_files
) AS c
```

You also don't need SUPER data type to perform this.  This can be done with json string parsing functions.

```
SELECT file_attr, json_extract_path_text(file_attr, 'deviceinfo') as deviceinfo, json_extract_path_text(file_attr, 'deviceinfo','DEVICE_ID') as device_id
FROM public.dc_ac_files
```

Comment: You are right! Few minutes ago I have found this solution too. My variant is: SELECT json_extract_path_text(json_extract_path_text(file_attr, 'deviceinfo'), 'DEVICE_ID') FROM public.dc_ac_files AS data; But may you variant more shortly

Comment: Good to hear.  As you see there is no need to nest the extract functions.  I see you have been posting a lot of questions recently.  Getting free answers is a good approach but if you need faster support helping clients get Redshift up and working is what I do.  You may want to consider getting some paid help.

Comment: how much it cost? It's not bad idea to get paid support. But also I want to boost my stackoverflow account.

Comment: I'd like to be respectful to SO's terms.  If you are interested in exploring you can contact me through my website - https://www.wadevelopment.co/